# loading partial view differently

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc and i know only two way one can render partial view like

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView1")
```

another one is to load partial view using jquery. i like to know is there any other ways around to load partial view.

when i render partialview like this way from my action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string name, string salary, string btnSubmit)
{
  return PartialView("TestPView");
}
```

then PartialView content was render in page but shared look & feel goes out from the page when PartialView shown.

what i need to include in partial view as a result common look & feel show when partial view render. please guide me and show me all the various way to load partial view. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is a layout and not a `PartialView`.
The `PartialView` provides you with the option to reuse a part of the view across several views.
The layout gives you the general look and feel of the website.

Here is the default example, that the VS generates for you :

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

Comment: can i put this line in partial view @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; } ?

Comment: A partial view can only be nested inside another view.
So, the only view that the layout can be applied to is the parent view.
It is similar to the concept of the MasterPage in asp.net.


But you can nest partial views.
So you can create a PartialView "Parent" and render several others inside. Although, it would require some if-logic.    


If it makes it any clearer, a layout is similar to MasterPage and PartialView is similar to UserControl.

Comment: @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; } if i include this line does it give any error?

Comment: In a regular view, it should be at the top of the view, in the same level as the @model :

`@using NpuRequest.Models;
@using NpuRequest.Helpers;
@using NpuRequest.Properties;

@model Step1
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }` - here is an example.

regarding a PartialView. I never tried it myself. But I guess it will throw an error while rendering the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below link. It will help u to better understand the possible ways of rendering the partial views in MVC:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/Q8V2130113-RenderPartial-vs-RenderAction-vs-Partial-vs-Action-in-MVC-Razor.html